# p:fileupload is fading image after fileUploadListener event

Tags: primefaces

p:fileupload is fading image after fileUploadListener event.

Some code.

```html
    <p:dialog id="dialogIncluirArquivo2" rendered="true" header="Inclusão de arquivo" widgetVar="modalIncluirArquivo2"
          resizable="false" closable="true" modal="false" width="750" height="auto">
    <h:form id="formAnexo2"  prependId="false"  >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top: 8px;"> 
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{tombamentoFace.handleFileUploadArquivo}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                              multiple="true" fileLimit="10" fileLimitMessage="É permitido o envio de 10 arquivos por requisição"
                              invalidFileMessage="Arquivo inválido!" immediate="true"
                              label="Incluir Arquvio" invalidSizeMessage="Arquivo maior que 5mb não é permitido!"
                              sizeLimit="5000000" update="panel2" auto="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h:outputText  value="Arquivo:" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px;" class="pull-right"/>
            </div>   
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h:commandLink actionListener="#{tombamentoFace.downloadAnexoArquivo(selectedArquivo)}" >
                    <h:outputText id="panel2" value="#{tombamentoFace.selectedArquivo.nome}" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; " class="pull-left"/>                       
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/>
        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <p:commandButton  value="Enviar arquivo" actionListener="#{tombamentoFace.vincularAnexoArquivo()}"
                                  styleClass="btn btn-flat btn-success"  style="color: #ecf0f1; height: 28px;" immediate="true" update="tab:table_arquivo " process="@this">
                </p:commandButton>     
                &nbsp;
                <p:commandLink value="Cancelar" update="panel2" actionListener="#{tombamentoFace.cancelarAnexoArquivo()}" process="@this"  immediate="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Is fading what image? Please create a [mcve]. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: The image that the fileupload shows when you select a file. It shows the image and shortly after fades it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is uploading the file.  If you don't want that change `auto="true"` to `auto="false"` and it won't automatically upload it and "fade the image" away.

Comment: how would I trigger the uploading so?

Comment: with `auto="false"` there should now be an "Upload" button visible for the user to manually upload when ready. This EXACT example does it: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml